# where are stored the metrics used in the graphs?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

where are the data stored that are used when I go to the "monitoring / metrics" menu?
Can't I use KQL to create more complex graphs?

[image]

The tables in the log menu are all empty (which seems logical to me since all the options are set to "off" in the "App Service Logs" menu)

Thanks !

Comment: Many (but not all) metrics values are stored in Azure Table Storage, in hidden tables you can see in Azure Storage Explorer, e.g. `$MetricsHourPrimaryTransactionBlob`

Answer (score 0):

> The tables in the log menu are all empty:

If your tables in the log menu are currently empty, it means that you have not configured the required diagnostic settings to send log data to Azure Monitor Logs.

To collect the logs from an app service to send it to log analytics/monitoring, you need to configure diagnostic settings by visiting your web app as shown below.

*Path*: `Web App >> Monitoring >> Logs`

[image]

Once it is configured, run a sample query as shown below to retrieve the app service-related logs.

```
AppServiceLogs 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2d)
```